# Diagnose a misterious detached HEAD in Git

Tags: git

I have a detached HEAD and would like to find out why.

I did `git status` which gave a `HEAD detached at 37f091b` amongst a lot of other output, so I overlooked it and committed, `git commit`.  Then I did `git status` again with the intention to please myself with a nice `nothing to commit, working directory clean` but had to see an ugly `HEAD detached from 37f091b`.

Now I don't understand where the `HEAD detached at 37f091b` came from at the first place. `A git log --decorate` shows

```
ffb3802 (HEAD)
37f091b (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
62220f1
```

To me that seems like `37f091b` is my master branch and `HEAD` should not have been detached before the commit and now I should have a simple linear history with no detached head either? How can I diagnose what went wrong?

(Looking at related questions I want to also note: `git stash list` shows no output. I was able to get rid of the whole thing by `git branch fix_detached_head ffb3802`, `git merge fix_detached_head` and `git branch -d fix_detached_head`. So my question is if I can somehow find out how I got myself even into this mess? If `37f091b` was detached from master when I committed `ffb3802`, that seems to indicate that the master branch must not have been at `37f091b`, but where then?)

Comment: You can use reflog to find out, when you go into detached head state: `git reflog HEAD`. BTW `37f091b` was **not** detached from `master`. `HEAD` was detached from `master`, but that does not forbid for `HEAD` to point to the same commit as `master`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That answers my question :-) I was not aware that being at the same revision at which `master` is does not mean being at `master`, and `git reflog HEAD` shows that I checked out `37f091b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things at play here.

"HEAD" is a magical pointer that tells git what you last checked out for your index, and usually, your working folder.

HEAD is a pointer, and it can either point directly at a commit (in which case HEAD is containing the SHA1 id of the commit) or a branch (in which case HEAD contains the name of the branch).

If you end up in a "detached HEAD" state it means HEAD is *not* pointing to a branch, but directly at a commit.

If you, in this state, make a commit, the commit will be made, HEAD will be moved to refer to your new commit, and your new commit will contain a parent pointer back to the previous commit that HEAD was referring to.

If, on the other hand, HEAD is pointing to a branch, and you do the above, make a commit, then everything above still happens, but the branch is also moved with it. The branch, *and* HEAD, will now point to this new commit.

There is also nothing that prevents HEAD to point to the same commit that is at the tip of a branch.

So with all the above information, here's what happened in your case.

For some reason you managed to check out the commit that `master` points to, instead of checking out `master`.

Your history thus looks like this:

```
          master
            v
*---*---*---*
            ^
          HEAD
```

Then you made a commit, which makes your history look like this:

```
          master
            v
*---*---*---*---*
                ^
              HEAD
```

If, on the other hand, you had checked out `master`, this is where you would've been before your last commit:

```
           HEAD
            v
          master
            v
*---*---*---*
```

And if you now did a commit:

```
               HEAD
                v
              master
                v
*---*---*---*---*
```

So the only mysterious part left to answer is how you ended up checking out a commit directly, instead of checking out a branch.

You can do this using various checkout commands:

```
git checkout "HEAD^"                      # I use quotes because I'm on Windows
git checkout 219874982739827982798723498  # SHA1 id of commit
git bisect ...                            # it will also check out commits directly
```

Answer (score 2):

As [PetSerAl said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738188/diagnose-a-misterious-detached-head-in-git#comment76458110_44738188), there is nothing that prevents Git from being in "detached HEAD" state *and* being on/at the same commit as the branch.  Precisely *how* you got into this state is not as easy to answer for certain, as there are multiple different ways to accomplish that, but first, let's define what it means for your head to be "detached" (or its opposite, which does not normally have a word for it, but logically should be "attached").

First, Git has the special name `HEAD`.  Maybe this should be a special symbol, so that it does not look like a name—Mercurial uses `.`, for instance—so that it's obviously *not* a branch name.  In fact, in Git since 1.8.5, you can usually write `@` instead of `HEAD`, but Git just translates this back to `HEAD`.  It's not the name of a branch, though: instead, it's a special file that usually, but not always, *contains* the name of a branch.  If it *doesn't* contain the name of a branch, then `HEAD` itself *acts like* a branch with no name (or with the name `HEAD`): the special `HEAD` file contains the hash ID of the tip commit of this anonymous branch.<sup>1</sup>

Your head is attached when `HEAD` contains the name of a branch.  That's it!  It's really that simple: if `HEAD` contains the name of a branch, it's attached, and if not, it's detached.

It's the *consequences* that matter.  If your head is attached, `git status` will tell you which branch name it has in it: `on branch master` or `on branch develop` or whatever.  Likewise, `git branch` will prefix the branch name with an asterisk.  So instead of saying "your head is attached"—well, sure! I haven't just been at the guillotine!—they say `on branch ...`.  When your head is attached, new commits go on *the current branch*.  The `git reset` command operates on *the current branch*.  Running `git log` looks at *the current branch*, and so on.  So having your head attached is usually pretty important.

Still, Git works just fine if your head *isn't* attached.  If your head is detached, `git branch` just doesn't say anything about it, and `git status` says `HEAD detached at ...` or `HEAD detached from ...`.  The `git reset` and `git log` commands use the commit hash ID stored in directly in the special `HEAD` file.

There are many ways to detach your head:

- `git checkout --detach branch-name` will check out the *tip commit of the given branch*, the same as `git checkout branch-name`, but will detach your head at the same time.  So you will be on the same commit, but not on the branch.
- `git checkout commit-hash` will check out one specific commit, and detach your head in the process.  This is true even if the commit you check out is the tip of a branch.
- `git checkout tag-name` will check out the commit to which the tag points, and detach your head in the process.
- `git checkout remote-tracking-branch-name` will check out the tip of the given remote-tracking branch, and detach your head in the process.

Except for the `--detach` option, these all share the same feature: the argument you gave to `git checkout` was a valid commit specifier, but was not a *branch name*.  Git will then check out that commit by detaching your head.

To re-attach your head to a branch, simply `git checkout branch-name`.

Any time you want to refer to some particular commit, you can do so by its raw hash ID, or by any method that Git can resolve to that hash ID.  [The gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) describes the many ways to name commits, such as using suffix operators like `master~5` or search operations like `':/fix bug 174'`.  But only branch names make `git checkout` keep your head attached.

---

<sup>1</sup>As you might guess from this, the `HEAD` file is extremely important.  In fact, it's so key, that if the file is missing, Git refuses to believe that your repository is a repository!  Since the `HEAD` file gets rewritten a lot in an active repository, the file itself will sometimes go missing if your computer crashes or loses power (depending on the ability of your computer to handle a bad failure like this).  Sometimes simply restoring the file, e.g., `echo ref: refs/heads/master > .git/HEAD`, suffices to get your repository back.

Comment: When talking to relative "Git noobs", I usually draw an analogy between `HEAD` and a "You are here" sign on a map.

Comment: What's the difference between when Git is detached _from_ a ref vs when it's detached _at_ a ref?

Comment: @IanDunn: This depends on your Git version. `git status` got smarter around Git 2.0, and then again a bit later: besides examining `HEAD` itself, `git status` looks into the *reflog entries* for `HEAD`. These tell Git whether you just recently ran a `git checkout` that detached `HEAD`, and it's still there at the commit you specified; or whether you did the `git checkout`, then moved HEAD around some more. The `at <name>` means "still there" and the `from <name>` means "was there, got moved since then".

Comment: Different Git vintages produce slightly different messages here. The really old ones never bother to look at the reflog entries at all, and just say "detached", without any more detail.