# Head still detached after Git reset -- hard <sha>

Tags: git

I ran a `git reset --hard mygoodhash`

I tried a bunch of this that and the other that didn't work as you can see in my commit history below. (all this because I accidentally 'pulled' a branch into my current working branch and the reset --merge didn't work.)

My understanding is that the above command would set the head back to the specified commit, but head is still detached.

Right now the code base is where I want it to be... HEAD@0, which is the same as the HEAD@2 and HEAD@10 here in the image below.

I would like to essentially delete everything back to HEAD@10 and attach the head to that commit.

I have not pushed this to any remote repos. It's all local so far.

Can some kind soul tell me what to do or point me to an article or post or whatever speaks to this?

[image: git reflog]

Comment: There are a lot of candidates for duplicates; this is the one I first thought was the most likely: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44738188/1256452. On re-reading your question, I'm not sure which one to go for.

Comment: The very short answer, though, is: re-attach `HEAD` *first*, *then* use `git reset --hard` to pick the commit you want for the branch name.

Comment: Thanks @torek.  But what is the command to re-attach HEAD?

Comment: `git checkout <branch-name>`: given an existing branch name, Git checks out that particular commit *and* attaches `HEAD` to that branch.

Comment: or `git checkout -b new_branch` if you want to attach to a new branch.

Comment: @torek I tried checking out the branch, but it reverts to an older version. So I created a new branch.

Comment: Remember that a branch *name* simply identifies one specific commit, which Git calls the *tip* of the branch. What `git reset` does, among all the other things it does too, is to *move* the name so that it identifies some other commit.

Comment: @torek thanks for the help. After creating the new branch, I thought I would try it again. so I ran reset --hard hash, and this time it worked. WTH? I don't know. I tried it three times before and the head stayed detached. But now it worked. So.... hmmm.... I got nothing. But all is good now except for a jacked up commit history, but I'll get over that.

Comment: The difference is probably whether you were on a branch before doing the reset or not. `git checkout master` followed by `git reset --hard <good_hash>` will set `master` to `<good_hash>` and have it checked out. If you were not on a branch when you did `git reset` the other times, then you would have stayed headless.